# Alignment near left margin in beamer

Tags: beamer, horizontal-alignment, lists

I'm trying to get beamer to have the same left margin for itemize environments and normal text (and for the symbols in the itemize environment to be aligned with the slide title). That is, I want a slide to look like:

Slide title

A line that is outside an itemize environment

o A first line that is inside an itemize environment

o A second line that is inside an itemize environment

But when I get the symbols of the itemize environment aligned with the title, the non-itemized lines have zero margin, i.e., they are right on the slide edge. The following MWE reproduces this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamersize{text margin left=0em,text margin right=1em}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]
  \frametitle{Test}
  Hello
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Hello again
  \end{itemize}  
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you perhaps after something like this?

```
\documentclass{beamer}

%\setbeamersize{text margin left=1em,text margin right=1em}
\setlength{\leftmargini}{1em}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}[circle]
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}
{
\raggedright\insertframetitle%
}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]
  \frametitle{Test}
  Hello
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Hello again
  \end{itemize}  
  \lipsum[2]
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is what I'm after, thanks. I'm curious, though: There is no beamer length that specifies the indent of the title line?

Comment: @user1362373 I was looking for it too but couldn't find it. You just have to set it manually using `\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}`. You can type `texdoc beamerouterthemedefault.sty` in your terminal and search for `\defbeamertemplate*{frametitle}` to see how the frametitle was defined and to see how you can use `beamercolorbox` environment for defining your custom frametitle, for instance. `:-)`