# How to make beamer text align with the title on the left margin?

Tags: beamer

In Beamer, the text doesn't align on the left margin with the title. It's as if all the text is indented (but it's not actually indented). How can I adjust Beamer so that the left margin of the title and the text is the same so they are aligned?

If you run the following code, you'll see the issue.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Title}
This text doesn't align on the left with the title.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/95300

Answer (score 1):

The default template for the frametitle uses a 0.3cm padding. You can change the left text margin to be the same:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamersize{text margin left=0.3cm}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Title}
This text doesn't align on the left with the title.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```